# How do I label expression alternatives with same precedence level?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, operator-precedence

With antlr4 I can label rule alternatives like this:

```
e : e '*' e # Mult
  | e '+' e # Add
  | INT # Int
  ;
```

From what I understand, in the rule above, Mult has higher precedence over Add because Mult comes before Add in the list of alternatives.

So for instance, if I wrote:

```
e : e '*'       e # Mult
  | e ('+'|'-') e # Add
  | INT # Int
  ;
```

The `+` in `1 + 2` and `-` in `4 - 2` have the same precedence.
However, now the alternative is not in the top level. Is there a way I can label the rules `e '+' e # Add` and `e '-' e #Sub` separately while still having both alternatives have same precedence level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid not. You can label the op though with op=('+'|'-') and then get the ctx.op() value during a tree walk and ask for its token type.